Postman Param Failure
I am thinking that I am doing this correctly and that the database receiving my API call does not allow for params to filter the results.  But, I think it would be good to run this by stackoverflow and see what YOU (yes, YOU, individually the person reading this RIGHT NOW) think.
One of the fields in the database table is TripLegID.  When I set a param Key in Postman to show me only the ones with the value 4, it still shows me all of the results.
Did I do something wrong?  Am I missing a step?


Looks like your APIs are ignoring the query parameters. To do this correctly, you can refer to the API specification docs (Swagger, etc.). Not necessarily the API will match database schema.
